# strophe.js group invite - handler not triggered

Tags: javascript, php, strophe, libstrophe

I have problem with my invitation handler. It is never fired. I can see invitation from group:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
        <message xmlns="jabber:client" from="epthi_795@conference.188.2.16.19" to="nikoladerikonjic@188.2.16.19">
            <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
                <invite from="sanjicabjelica@188.2.16.19">
                    <reason>Please join me in conference.</reason>
                </invite>
            </x>
            <x xmlns="jabber:x:conference" jid="epthi_795@conference.188.2.16.19"/>
        </message>
</body>
```

but on_message handler is not fired. Because no type is defined.

When I put `Chat.connection.addHandler(Chat.on_message,null, "message", null,null,null,null);`

Invitations is shown but then all messages group or chat are handled by this. I want to me able to  have

```
Chat.connection.addHandler(Chat.on_message,null, "message", "chat");
Chat.connection.addHandler(Chat.on_message,null, "message", "groupchat");
```

for separate type of messages.

I am going around i circles for two days with this. Help!?

In other words what to put in addHandler for messages that contain invite?

**UPDATE**

I have to put

```
Chat.connection.addHandler(Chat.on_message,null, "message");
```

before I did invite.

I do not understand why is that? Does anyone has idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 handlers you started with require a type. The invite does not have a type. The handler I use for invites looks for the namespace instead. That way it's separated from my message handler.

connection.addHandler(onInvite, 'jabber:x:conference');

Comment: can you help with decline message invite? what namespace did you use? can you show me stanza? I have var msg = $msg({"to" : from}).c("x", {"xmlns" : Strophe.NS.MUC_USER}).c("decline", {"to" : sender}); but this is not working. Can you help?

Comment: I just add an "action" attribute and look for it when my onInvite gets called.

Comment: var msg = $msg({to: toJid, from: fromJid}).c('x', {xmlns: 'jabber:x:conference',
                                jid: roomJid,
                                action: 'deny'
                            }).tree();

                            connection().send(msg);

Comment: var action = el.getAttribute('action'); if(action==='deny'){//declined}